# Wrong replacement of double quotes instead of double angle quotes VBA Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to replace all `Left and Right double angle quotes` chr(171) and chr(187) followed by a space chr(32) that is `«` or `»` with only the chr(171) or chr(187) respectively.

Replace this "**« Abc**"  for this "**«Abc**"

and

Replace this "**xyz »**"  for this "**xyz»**"

I´m using the code below, but after the replacement, the character is a double quote `“` instead a double angle quote `«`

```
Sub ReplaceDoubleAngleQuotes()

With Selection.Find
 .ClearFormatting
 .Text = Chr(171) & Chr(32)
 .Replacement.ClearFormatting
 .Replacement.Text = Chr(171)
 .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
 Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With

End Sub
```

How to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `Chr(171)` and `Chr(187)` are not angle quotes. They might be on certain locales, but on others they will be different characters. You want to use `ChrW(171)` and `ChrW(187)`.

With that in mind, your code actually works and correctly replaces the quote, but then Word's <kbd>File</kbd> - <kbd>Options</kbd> - <kbd>Proofing</kbd> - <kbd>AutoCorrect options</kbd> - <kbd>AutoFormat As You Type</kbd> - <kbd>Straight quotes with smart quotes</kbd> kicks in and replaces the final `«` with `“`.

One option is to disable that feature:

```vb
Dim prev_value As Boolean
prev_value = Application.Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes

Application.Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes = False

With Selection.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Execute FindText:=ChrW$(171) & " ", _
           ReplaceWith:=ChrW$(171), _
           Replace:=wdReplaceAll, _
           Forward:=True, _
           Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With

Application.Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes = prev_value
```

Another option is to use wildcard matching, capture the anlge quote as a separate group and mention it in the replacement wildcard:

```vb
With Selection.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Execute FindText:="(" & ChrW$(171) & ")( )", _
           MatchWildcards:=True, _ 
           ReplaceWith:="\1", _
           Replace:=wdReplaceAll, _
           Forward:=True, _
           Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With
```

For some reason the smart quote feature does not kick in in this case.

Comment: Thanks so much for the solutions provided. I didn´t now about `ChrW()` nor that is possible to make group matching/replace with wildcards in Ms Word.

Answer (score 3):

Probably You got turned on `.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes` and your Word is changing chr(171) («) into "".

If You want to just turn this off for function Find&Replace do sth like:

```
Sub ReplaceDoubleAngleQuotes()

Dim userSmartQuotes As Boolean

userSmartQuotes = Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes
Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes = False

With Selection.Find
 .ClearFormatting
 .Text = Chr(171) & Chr(32)
 .Replacement.ClearFormatting
 .Replacement.Text = Chr(171)
 .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
 Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With

Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes = userSmartQuotes

End Sub
```

If You want to just turn this off (without returning to main setting) put

```
Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes = False
```

at the beginning and that is all.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I didn't know about this option of smart quotes. Something new learned.